# UL overlap, float:left image

Tags: html, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do my list item bullets overlap floating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710158/why-do-my-list-item-bullets-overlap-floating-elements)

**I've been having this problem with ul's next to a floating image**

**Here is the code i've been using**

```
<img src="abc.jpg" width="300" height="375" style="float:left;" /> Hello world isn't this amazing
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <!--list shortened for readability-->
</ul>
<p>Extra sample text here</p>
```

**Result**

[image: Default float problem]

**If it's changed to**

```
<ul style="overflow:auto;">
```

[image: Too long]

**The list carries on past the image, not what i want**

**Also trying this below gives the wrong result**

```
<ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
```

[image: Green text are comments]

**Photoshop of what i want**
[image: What i want]

Comment: Please clarify on what you are trying to achieve. What is the question?

Comment: I added a photoshop of what i want as that last image the purple sections is where it moved from

Answer (score 2):

While using list-style-position: inside on the , also remove the padding-left of . The padding is usually defined by the browser. As an alternative, you could leave list-style-position: outside and increase the margin-left of  until the bullets aren't overlapping.

Comment: There didn't seem to be any padding-left also i want the bullets below to not have a large padding-left

Comment: I checked an example I once worked with where I had the exact same problem and there simply was no nice solution. I ended up using overflow: hidden on the <ul> with list-style-position: outside, just like in your 2nd example.

Answer (score 1):

you can put the ul inside a div and make the div float left after the image

Comment: That resulted in http://dl.dropbox.com/u/454062/ZScreen/2012-03/Screenshot-2012-03-12_10.08.52.png

Answer (score 0):

This is a great reference for how CSS works: [CSS2.1#floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)

`<ul>` is a block element so you can make the  float next to the image without any extra div like so using inline styles:

```
<ul style="float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add `margin-right: 20px;` to your image. Or, if you need to move only your list and leave the surrounding text in place, add `margin-left: 40px;` to the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another fugly, but working solution is to put each li in a separate ul, and set overflow:hidden on the uls, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/xA9n8/