# align bullets with main text while wrapping around image

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists

I'm completely stumped trying to fix an issue..

As the image below shows, i have an image on the left, text on the right that wraps around the image, i also have a list (ul) in this text, what i want is to align the bullet with the rest of the text above it instead of being outside the text while also keeping it wrapping around the image and the lines within the single list item aligning with each other instead of creating hanging paragraphs..

Is this even possible?

[image: page design currently]

Included the HTML below...

```
<div class="entry-content">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Pinterest" />
<p>Haven’t worked out how Pinterest could benefit you? An image sharing site that allows users to "pin" what they find onto a virtual pin board for others to enjoy, last year it reached the 10 million monthly visitors mark, the fastest of any standalone site to do so</p>
<ul>
    <li>Integration: By connecting Pinterest with your website and other social media platforms you can publish your findings in a variety of ways.</li>
    <li>Collaboration: Pinterest can allow you to share ideas within your business or with clients. Why not invite people to collaborate with you on boards?</li>
    <li>Sharing: Position yourself as a valuable resource. Create a board for your niche subject and lead the way with new ideas in your industry.</li>
    <li>Information: Data is key to the growth and development of your business. Keep an eye on what&#8217;s being pinned, how often and by how many people.</li>
    <li>Enjoyment: Pinterest gives you the opportunity to represent your company in a way it&#8217;s never usually seen. Enjoy the challenge of showing your company in a new light and build your community by pinning the inspiration of other users.</li>
</ul>
<p>As a design and digital agency Pinterest is right up our street. We&#8217;ve  started using it to collage all the wonderful things we enjoy, including ideas for our studio, general food for thought and to help us find inspiration for our journal.</p>
<p>How are you using or planning to use Pinterest?</p></div>
```

CSS included as well..

```
.blog-post img       {width:auto; float:left; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:40px;}
.blog-post p         {margin-bottom:26px;}
.blog-post .descr ul {list-style:none; margin-left:0; padding-left:1em; text-indent:-1em;}
```

Below i've included an mockup of what i'm trying to aim for.

[image: desired effect]

Comment: do you still want the bullet points?

Comment: well yeah the bullets need to be there.. what other options are there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do my list item bullets overlap floating elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710158/why-do-my-list-item-bullets-overlap-floating-elements)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but for future reference, try this:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

Add that to either UL or LI elements

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to the bottom of the image, and it should push the text back in place.

Comment: the image does have a bottom margin, it's the bullets i want to move to align with the text above them with affecting anything else such as the items below the image and the wrapping around the image.

Answer (score -2):

All you need is to do is `float:left` the image. The rendering engine should take care of the rest.

Comment: How do you know it isn't already being floated? This is a padding/margin related issue.

Comment: hi, the image is being floated at the moment.

Comment: Indeed, floating the image is often what causes this issue.

Comment: That is the problem, not the solution. A left-floated image causes havoc with bullets in a wrapped list.