# Prevent bullets overlapping in IE9+ with floating left image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with bullets in IE9+ 
http://www.qualichemlab.it/test/internazionalizzazione-e-green-economy/green-economy-e-environmental-management/

I've already created a ie.css called via conditional comments, but no way.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden;` on the `ul`

This works in ie10/11

Explanation:
[Why do my list item bullets overlap floating elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710158/why-do-my-list-item-bullets-overlap-floating-elements?rq=1)