# Missing indent for <ul> <li> when div text is wrapped with another div

Tags: html, css

I have a page in which the right column content is wrapped around the left column. If I have a simple text or paragraph then the page looks fine. 
But suppose the right side content contains a `<ul>` `<li>` list element the whole indentation is lost.

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8DB6e/1/

It appears the problem is the `wrapRightCol` div container is overlaid on top of `leftcol`. Ideally `wrapRightCol` container should stay to the right of `leftcol` and then wrap around.

Can anyone help me here to correct the styles so that I can have the list element placed correctly beside left column with default indentation(i.e with proper padding & margin).

N.B: I am using the Bootstrap UI library

Fiddle HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="leftcol" >
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapRightCol">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <h4>Example list</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
        <p>  Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Style:

```
.wrapper {
    float: left;
}
.leftcol {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [`list-style-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) property:

```
li{
    list-style-position:inside
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8DB6e/2/)

Comment: Using list-style-position the dot before each item becomes part of the text and it looks weird.
See this: http://jsfiddle.net/8DB6e/8/

Comment: Sounds like you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8DB6e/9/ -- Taken from the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11904121/1612146

Answer (score 1):

First Method

```
  .wrapRightCol ul{ overflow: hidden; }
```

Second method

```
 li{
    list-style-position:inside
}
```

[**`Demo1`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/8DB6e/6/)

[**`Demo2`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/8DB6e/10/)

Comment: Sorry this works but my right column content should wrap around the left col at the bottom.

Comment: Yes this works but it fails when I have more items in the list. Can we make the exceeding items wrap also along with indent.
See: http://jsfiddle.net/8DB6e/7/

Answer (score 0):

`list-style-position:inside` will bring the bullets inline with the other text in `.wrapRightCol` but another alternative would be to add extra `margin-right` to `.leftCol` to move the right column away from the left and provide some gutter - `margin-right:1.5em` does the trick.

Based on the fiddle, there is no need for `float:left` on the `.wrapper` or `clear:right` on the `.leftcol`.

http://jsfiddle.net/z7pVh/