# Lists Not Rendering Correctly in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My unordered lists look great in every browser by IE (go figure).

The bullets get pushed out to the far left, and not next to the content.

Any idea what I need to do?

Link to page: http://www.agrm.org/agrm/2015_AGRM_CONVENTION.asp

Link to screenshot in IE10: http://www.screencast.com/t/AjOv3KS1Heu

Comment: First, describe what the `ul` should look like, and what it looks like instead. Then add the _relevant_ HTML and CSS to the question (not all the code you have).

Comment: Sorry, first time posting. Can't embed an image. I'll explain better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do my list item bullets overlap floating elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710158/why-do-my-list-item-bullets-overlap-floating-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand the layout in not properly arranged.

If you inspect via firebug you will see that the UL is going way out of its area and overlapping the image.

What you need to do is set proper containers. The image is float left, that is correct and now what you need to do is wrap the entire content in a div, give it a width and make it float left or right according to your requirement.

As there is no layout containing the content the ul thinks it has the entire space.